# How do I tranfer data from one API to another API in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created API-1 which reads data from a remote database. How to create an API-2 which will read the data from API-1 & display it?

Comment: Start with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: There is an example of how to use it in the article linked.

Comment: @AyaneshChoudhury , I think your problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have given very limited information. Based on that I tried to give you answer. You just add another web API controller API2. As you said your API1 reading information which have httpget. So when you added API2 let see you implement httpGet in API as well and just use HttpClient service class to call API1. Below is code to in API2

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new 
Uri("http://localhost:XXXXX/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //GET Method  
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/API1");
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = 
result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string[]>();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
            }
        }
```

This is just example.

Comment: You can also HttpWebRequest instead of using HttpClient to call your API

Comment: You can use `HttpWebRequest` but it is not recommended. `HttpClient` is the preferred approach as it is much more scalable. Also, why block threads instead of using asynchrony?

Comment: @ColinM,  This is working for me and to wait for response by service. I think, this is not blocking the main thread, but your point is of research. Please share if you find any thing.

Comment: It's of research but also performance. The code works and is fine, but you're using `.Wait()` and `.Result` which are both thread blocking operations. `HttpClient` supports `async` and `await` and promotes it's usage as asynchronous programming is not thread blocking.

Comment: Great, can please provide some sample example on this?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/